# Rate Limit the Nodejs Module Request

Tags: node.js, node-request

So I'm trying to create a data scraper with Nodejs using the Request module. I'd like to limit the concurrency to 1 domains on a 20ms cycle to go through 50,000 urls.

When I execute the code, I'm DoS-ing the network with the 40Gbps bandwidth my system has access to... This creates local problems and remote problems.

The 5 concurrent scans on a 120ms cycle for 50k domains (if I calculated correctly) will finish the list in ~20 minutes and will not create any issues remotely at least.

The code I'm testing with:

```
var urls = // data from mongodb

urls.forEach(fn(url) {
  // pseudo
  request the url
    process
});
```

The forEach function executes instantly "queueing" all urls and tries to fetch all. It seems impossible to do a delay on each loop. All google searches seem to show how to rate limit incoming request to your server/api. Same thing appears to happen with a for loop as well. Impossible to control how fast the loops execute. I'm missing something probably or the code logic is wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For simplification your code implementation use `async/await` and Promises instead callbacks.
2. Use package [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for run Promised requests.
3. Use `p-map` or similar approach form [promise-fun](https://github.com/sindresorhus/promise-fun)

There is copypasted example:

```
const pMap = require('p-map');

const urls = [
'sindresorhus.com',
'ava.li',
'github.com',
…
];

console.log(urls.length);
//=> 100

const mapper = url => {
return fetchStats(url); //=> Promise
};

pMap(urls, mapper, {concurrency: 5}).then(result => {
console.log(result);
//=> [{url: 'sindresorhus.com', stats: {…}}, …]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. So I came up with this https://pastebin.com/0RSyDzmK the only problem is when it gets 404's or non 2xx statusCodes...

Comment: At async function you don't need to use catch at promise chain. Use try+catch as regular function. Also test got request without parsing, i think you have mistake at this place.

Comment: Do you mean I should wrap the const response = await got.get(url.url, { headers: {"User-Agent": "Something Something"} }) into a try catch block?

Comment: Hi there, I did the following which seems to work and not stop the Nodejs from crashing when encountering non 2xx errors (eg. 404) https://pastebin.com/S9v6apWL